# Bluetooth service unable to start without "systemctl restart bluetooth"

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, bluetooth, iwlwifi

I've just received a new HP unit.

By default, after a fresh boot, the Bluetooth service is unable to start correctly and does not find any device to pair with nor the NetworkManager's Bluetooth indicator changes from "off" to "on" state.

Device:
`Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. AX200 Bluetooth`

Logs indicate a problem with rfkill :

```
22:22:46 bluetoothd: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
22:22:46 bluetoothd: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
22:19:44 bluetoothd: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
22:13:44 bluetoothd: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
22:13:43 bluetoothd: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
```

Indeed, it is "soft blocked" :

```
# rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

If I unblock it :

`# sudo rfkill unblock Bluetooth`

and restart it

`# sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`

It immediately works and connects to devices correctly,however if I switched it back off and on using NetworkManager applet, it is again not working and Bluetooth stays in "off" state.

[image: screenshot]

So it seems the NetworkManager is unable to activate it back. Only then a subsequent `systemctl restart bluetooth` command seems to make it work again and change to "on" state as well as start listing nearby devices.

So, in short, NetworkManager is unable to activate the Bluetooth interface.

Note that concerning WiFi, it works as expected.

The issue is persistent across all kernels (as far as I have tested) on this device except `5.4.x`. Independent of Ubuntu version, same issue on 20.04, 20.10 & 21.04. Same issue on boot from USB. Works with no issues on Windows.

The issue is occasionally not present after I restart the computer, but most of the time it is.

Answer (score 2):

On my HP elitebook G2 840, Intel® Core™ i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz × 4
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Linux 5.8.0-53-generic x86_64 this worked a bit:

Editing config file:
sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf

Changing AutoEnable to True, taking out the #

Taking out # at Reconnect=7

Taking out # at Fastconnectable

Save and exit.

As per this post:

https://www.makeuseof.com/fix-bluetooth-connectivity-issues-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Unfortunately does not seem to have had any effect on my setup. I am actually on HP Elitedesk so hoped for a good result.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this with some help.
First open terminal make yourself sudo with command:

```
sudo -i
cd /etc/init.d
```

Use a text editor put this inside:

```
sleep 10
systemctl restart bluetooth.service
```

Save this script as `BLUETOOTHFIX.sh`. Then enable to execute by terminal:

```
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/BLUETOOTHFIX.sh
chmod +x /etc/init.d/BLUETOOTHFIX.sh
ln -s /etc/init.d/BLUETOOTHFIX.sh /etc/rc3.d/S99BLUETOOTHFIX.sh
```

Comment: Code formatting? and same answer posted on U&L, [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/700904/97255)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with Ubuntu 22.04. Finally I fixed it from below steps.

1. **Software Update** > **Additional Drivers**.
2. Installed wireless driver. (default selected "do not use the
   device". I selected respective drivers and installed it).
3. **Settings** > **Wi-FI** > Turn on and turn off **Airplane Mode**.
4. **Settings** > **Blutooth** > Turn on

----------------- Update ------------------

After restart above solution not worked.

I tried **sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth** and got below logs.

```
Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM43142A0-04ca-2009.hcd'
```

As per the [this article](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware), I download the relevant xxx.hcd file (BCM43142A0-04ca-2009.hcd in my case) and move to the /lib/firmware/brcm folder. After reboot firmware successfully loaded and bluetooth worked properly.