# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS bluetooth not opening

Tags: bluetooth

[Bluetooth not opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsbZQ.png)
First booth up it's work fine but it's not open now.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead, copy-and-paste the actual text into your Question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bluetooth service unable to start without "systemctl restart bluetooth"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333957/bluetooth-service-unable-to-start-without-systemctl-restart-bluetooth)

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo systemctl start bluetooth
```

If nothing then `sudo apt install bluez` run `bluez` and use GUI to connect.

You can also try `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`, but keep in mind that that will restart all your networked connections.

Comment: use `systemctl`, not `service`

Comment: @warren Thank you, should I add that ?

Comment: I'd reword from "service ... start" to "systemctl start ..." :)

Comment: @warren done, thanks !